# Conditional replacement of column values in a dataframe using R

Tags: r, replace

Let's make a dummy dataset

```
ll = data.frame(rbind(c(2,3,5), c(3,4,6), c(9,4,9)))
colnames(ll)<-c("b", "c", "a")
> ll
  b c a
1 2 3 5
2 3 4 6
3 9 4 9

P = data.frame(cbind(c(3,5), c(4,6), c(8,7)))
colnames(P)<-c("a", "b", "c")
> P
  a b c
1 3 4 8
2 5 6 7
```

I want to create a new dataframe where the values in each column of ll would be turned into 0 when it is less than corresponding values of a,b, & c in the first row of P; in other words, I'd like to see

```
> new_ll
  b c a
1 0 0 5
2 0 0 6
3 9 0 9
```

so I tried it this way

```
nn=c("a", "b", "c")
new_ll = sapply(nn, function(i) 
  ll[,paste0(i)][ll[,paste0(i)] < P[,paste0(i)][1]] <- 0)
```

But it doesn't work for some reason! I must be doing a silly mistake in my script!! Any idea?

```
> new_ll
a b c 
0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the values in `ll` that are smaller than the first row of `P` with an `apply`:

```
t(apply(ll, 1, function(x) x<P[1,][colnames(ll)]))
      [,1] [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Here, the first row of `P` is ordered to match `ll`, then the elements are compared.

Credit to Ananda Mahto for recognizing that `apply` is not required:

```
ll < c(P[1, names(ll)])
         b    c     a
[1,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

The `TRUE` values show where you want to substitute with 0:

```
ll[ ll < c(P[1, names(ll)]) ] <- 0
ll
  b c a
1 0 0 5
2 0 0 6
3 9 0 9
```

To fix your code, you want something like this:

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(names(ll), function(i) {
    ll[,i][ll[,i] < P[,i][1]] <- 0
    return(ll[i])}))
  b c a
1 0 0 5
2 0 0 6
3 9 0 9
```

What's changed?  First, `sapply` is changed to `lapply` and the function returns a vector for each iteration.  Second, the names are presented in the correct order for the expected results.  Third, the results are put together with `cbind` to get the final matrix.  As a bonus, the redundant calls to `paste0` have been removed.

Comment: thanks, but what is wrong with my code ... i mean why sapply doesn't work?

Comment: Your code doesn't work because the function doesn't return anything useful.

Comment: I don't think `apply` is required here. Can't you just do `ll[ll < c(P[1, names(ll)])] <- 0`?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `mapply`, which applies the function to the each corresponding element.  Here, the `ll` and `P` are both `data.frames`.  So, it applies the function for each column and does the recycling also.  Here, I matched the `column names` of `P` with that of `ll` (similar to @Matthew Lundberg) and looked for which elements of `ll` in each column is `<` than the corresponding column (the one row of `P` gets recycled) and returns a logical index.  Then the elements that matches the logical condition are assigned to `0`.

```
indx <- mapply(`<`, ll, P[1,][names(ll)])
new_ll <- ll
new_ll[indx] <- 0
new_ll
 #  b c a
 #1 0 0 5
 #2 0 0 6
 #3 9 0 9
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you know that `ll` and `P` are numeric you can do it also as

```
llm <- as.matrix(ll)
pv <- as.numeric(P[1, colnames(llm)])  
llm[sweep(llm, 2, pv, `<=`)] <- 0
data.frame(llm)
#   b c a
# 1 0 0 5
# 2 0 0 6
# 3 9 0 9
```